# Wiring 6000W 110V Crepe Maker

Tags: kitchens, appliances

I have a China-made commercial size crepe maker with double griddles/plates. The back plate states that it is 110V, 5400W, while the online data lists it as 6000w (2x3000). It comes without a plug, since it is supposed to be wired directly. The wire that is factory installed is (3x) 4.0mm = 12awg in heavy insulation. There is no separate power switch on the appliance, only thermostat switches for each plate.
How do I protect this properly?  If I wire it directly, I cannot go with a circuit breaker larger than 30amps with 12awg wire? 6-50 plug into a 6-50 outlet?

Comment: Appliance wire is special - it’s of fixed (short) length and usually inside a housing, so it’s not necessarily unusual to see #12 wire in a device that uses 50A. Given that it draws at least 49A, you need to put it on at least a 50A circuit with the corresponding building wiring.

Comment: If the data plate is correct (5400W @ 110V) this thing will draw more like 56A at 125V (actual US service voltage these days), needing at least a 60A circuit. You should seriously consider returning this and getting one that operates on 240V - the circuit and wiring will be much more reasonable.

Comment: There’s also a good chance that the device you have is not UL (or other NRTL) listed and should be rejected on those grounds alone.

Comment: Makes absolutely no sense to have an appliance that large on 110-ishV. There are a **lot** of red flags here. I'd be really skeptical of proper design/testing/certification, which could lead to serious problems with a hard-wired device (e.g., if there is a fire insurance may not pay). Manufacturer? Model #? Any other details?

Comment: if each element is 110v 3000w on a commercial piece of cooking equipment connecting then putting them in series for 240v would workout with 12 gauge fixture wire and a 30 amp double pole. Many commercial appliances have this and even 3 phase wiring that can be configured differently for different countries. The one thing to verify is that it is a listed device. #12 fixture wire is rated for 23 amps see table 402.5 , a feeder receptacle 30 amp circuit with #10 and it would look like electric fryers I have installed. Remember appliance internals do not use the wire gauge for premises wiring.

Comment: Can you get us the make and model # of this thing?

Comment: The design and the back plate are almost identical to this one: https://www.walmart.com/ip/Aohuada-Commercial-16-inch-Heavy-Duty-Dual-Crepe-Maker-6KW-110V-Electric-Pan-Maker-Nonstick-Hotplate-Adjustable-Temperature-Control-Roti-Tortilla-Egg/620100259
However, the wattage is different.. and the model number is CG-2. The device is indeed CE certified, but not UL...

Comment: I think it might be this one: https://www.ebay.com/itm/294775274125

Comment: CE doesn't mean anything legally in this context.

Comment: @EdBeal Wiring the elements in series works in general (when both should always be on at the same time), but that’s not the case here. They have independent temperature controls and will naturally heat and cool differently depending on how much food is applied and when. It’d be like wiring two separate stove burners in series.

Comment: Use a plug **with a neutral wire** (NEMA14-30) and the elements can operate independently-in-series. Basically a 30A MWBC. But it's unlisted so it should not be installed...

Comment: "There is no separate power switch on the appliance, only thermostat switches for each plate." Do the thermostats go all the way down to zero (meaning off), or do you plan on turning this on/off at the breaker each time you use it?

Comment: They do go to 0F/off position, so that part should be ok.

Comment: You will spend at least 10 times as much on code-compatible wiring as you will on a COTS  110X15A crepe-griddle.

Comment: @nobody add the neutral to the center tap it’s all in how it is wired I was suggesting the only legal way in the US to connect something like this as it is similar to some multi phase systems I have connected.

Comment: CE is not an independent 3rd party testing lab. 99.9% of all CE marks seen in the USA are counterfeit.  It's a "promise to self-test" mark, but it only applies to manufacturers who have a physical bricks-and-mortar presence in Europe (i.e. something for the authorities to seize if they lie).  The Chinese forge it with impunity.  Unfortunately, Walmart has taken to including Amazon listings; Amazon allows 3rd party sellers who are just as bad as eBay. (and Sears includes eBay listings). The ripoffs of the American consumer never cease.

Comment: Allegedly "The Bottom Drawer Type Sundry Trough Can Handle The Residue In Time".    That's gotta be worth something, no?

Comment: Well, my wife likes the way it looks, and it's for home use :) I opened it up and it seems pretty straightforward to re-wire it so that there are two independent plugs, one for each plate. Since I have 50amps on 220/240V on that line, I can easily add two outlets there, with another breaker... Thanks for all advice, it really helps to explore options with people who know more about this than I do ;)

Answer (score 7):

### You've been had.

That thing is not UL listed. It is not safe in 2 respects:

- Its griddle is made of mystery material, and food should not touch it (especially food you are serving to customers).
- All the electrics are dangerous. This is the kind of thing you find in the ashes of a burned down restaurant.  When they do, and they will... the city, insurer and building owner (mortgage lender) will turn on you with a vengeance.

It's probably not going to last, anyway.

But yes, as others said you will spend more getting power to this thing than you would buying a proper unit. *SMH 110V what are they thinking?  Who would ever build a 2500W unit to that spec, let alone two of them?* The only thing I can think is UK requires 110V center-grounded (55V phase to ground) for construction sites; maybe they require that for food trucks also.   110V?  We haven't used that since before the war.

Of course lots of people call it "110V" for the same reason we call all tissue "Kleenex" and all copies "Xerox".  But putting that *in the frickin' specification* (such that it is) just goes to show how it was written by marketers who just say what you wanna hear.

Any real product would state 120-125V instead of 110V, and any competent machine of that size would be 240V. (that'd be 10.5 amps per head, perfectly achievable).

The "bright line" standard for product quality is the standards curated by UL, informally called the "UL White Book".   UL is also a *nationally recognized, independent testing lab (NRTL)* who can certify equipment to that standard and assure manufacturing continues to conform (i.e. the maker doesn't cheapen the production). There other testing labs such as ETL and CSA, but CE is definitely not a testing lab, and is their choice of mark "to fake".  EU authorities in Brussels don't care if somebody fakes the mark outside the EU.

There's also a huge problem with 55A on #12 wire.   Certainly, UL grants *some* margin on account of *appliance cords* being in open air not packed in insulation. But I could see 28A on #12, certainly not twice that.

So this thing is fraudulent at every level.

### What if we actually had a 110V 6000W thing to power?

Wow, just wow.  6000W / 110V = 54.5A actual.

We need to derate that 125%, so that brings us to 68.2 amps.  Wow.

Even if the 5400W label (not VA???) is accurate (not likely), you're still at 49A actual and 62A at derate.

*Oh, but it's even worse*.  This will be a resistive heater, and you are applying at least 11% *over-voltage* to it since our power is nominally 120V but really 122-123V usually.  That means current will also rise by 11%, and total power by 21%.  Rapid burnout of the appliance, but it also means we need to provision more power.

So now it's not 68.2A, it's 75A at "6000W".
Not 62A but 69A at "5400W".

This is crazy.

See, this is why you know the appliance manufacturer is not legitimate.  Every proper manufacturer knows the derate tables *like the back of their hand*.  You will consitently find nameplates *just under* 16A, 24A, 32A, 40A, 48A - because those x 125% = a common circuit/breaker size.

The max on a 120V/20A circuit is 1920W (120V @ 16A). Any larger than that, a manufacturer is going to step up to 240V. Because they know perfectly well that this is less costly for the customer to wire up.

They're not going to put you in a situation like this vendor has, of using an awkward and unsupported voltage, and forcing you to spend a fortune provisioning the circuit.

And they also know that restaurants are taking commercial power at commercial tariffs, and the power company doesn't allow them to have a highly lopsided load drawing heavily from one phase, which is what this thing does.

I think they said 110V because they wanted dumb consumers to go "I know that voltage! I have that at home!" so they would think they could just plug it into the wall.  They don't seem to care about the installations failing.

### Let's get down to it. Single-phase wiring.

Unfortunately we can't drive this thing split-phase (1 burner per phase) because it's only a 3-wire cord. 2 must be ground and neutral, so that only leaves one for hot. Yet another botch in the design.

So the nameplate should rule, with adjustments for over-voltage... so we need 69A wiring and a 70A breaker.

There are no usable sockets for current this large, so it must be hard-wired.  You'll need a BIG box for those splices.

They don't make 70A single-pole breakers (what would ever use it??) so you'll need a 70A 2-pole and use one pole.

Wire needs to be, wow, #4 copper, *that won't be expensive!* And you'll need three Polaris couplers to couple to it, at about $20 a pop.   You might be able to undersize the ground to #6 or #8, at that size an ILSCO "Mac Block Connector" is a bit cheaper than Polaris.

Since you're into snake-wrestling anyway, it would be slightly easier and much cheaper to use #3 aluminum.  #2 would also suffice.  The Polaris is rated for aluminum which solves "the aluminum wiring problem" some worry about.

You will need an inch-pound torque wrench to set torque correctly, if you don't want "the *other* wiring problem" that both copper and aluminum are equally vulnerable.

Have fun watching the 4.0mm<sup>2</sup> wire glow cherry red!

Slamming one pole with *this much power* is going to require a Load Calculation be done to make sure you don't blow your service out.  That's beyond the scope of an answer here, but it needs to be done.

**You realize, circuits of this size require a permit to be pulled and inspections done.  The issuer/inspector will be amazed by this 70A/110V griddle, will take a closer look at it, and WILL red-flag it**.