# 60A 120V draw spikes for house

Tags: electrical

The power company installed a monitoring device at the street where the main power connects to the runs to the house and said they saw something weird with some large 120V load draws (looks like around 60A on one channel) at certain times.  I don't think there are any 120V devices which could draw this much load, nor does it appear any breakers would allow that much load without getting tripped.  Please see below for screenshots of the recordings.  The vertical orange lines are to make it easier to see what lines up with what.  The second image is a zoom in near the second vertical orange line.

In case it's helpful, the context of the power company's investigation was lights flickering at various times throughout the house and in some cases shutting off for 1-2 sec, including multiple ceiling fans shutting off momentarily, not necessarily at the same time, and the lights sometimes getting very bright before shutting off.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any induction heating in the house (range)? Was the cloths dryer running about 8PM?

Comment: You don't have [one of these](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/244440/wiring-6000w-110v-crepe-maker), do you?

Comment: The diagram looks *much* more finely detailed than the typical 15-minute chunks. Have you had any breaker trips lately? Any HVAC or other motor-driven equipment that instead of starting up in 5 seconds is struggling for 30 seconds until it finally gets going?

Comment: Do you know which 240V (double pole) breakers feed what?

Comment: @Gil no induction heating (gas range), and clothes dryer is gas

Comment: Haha nothing like that @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I've occasionally had the microwave breaker trip but that's only been a few times.  They sampled at 10 second increments.  Nothing I'm aware of that has any struggles starting up.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I don't know which go to which unfortunately

Comment: Wow, the fridge startup should be <1 second long, not >10 seconds.  I wonder if that L-shaped load is something else.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica my understanding was it is an instantaneous sample every 10 sec if that makes a difference. Btw I replied on your answer with the results of doing the test you recommended. Thx

Answer (score 3):

Well there's one "L-shaped" load on phase L2 that's like a heartbeat.  You can see it in full detail: coarsely once an hour, it throws a 20A spike, runs steady-state at 1A for 20-ish minutes, and shuts off.  You can see the shelf on the fine-detail chart. (it's often overlapped with other cyclic loads, but once or twice it stands alone.) **That's a refrigerator**.

It does seem a little odd that a fridge would kick a 20A spike for long enough to detect.

What's weird about your spike is it's not L-shaped.  There's no motor that runs for any appreciable length of time afterward - maybe a minute tops.  So some sort of intermittent load like a shredder or can opener?  Probably a larger machine, though.  Nice burly garbage disposal?

Usually in evenings, although Sunday and Tuesday afternoon and evening. Very late (10:00?) Monday night. I might guess it was a table saw.  That'd be about right.

We really can't guess at your loads.  A picture of a bunch of circuit breakers doesn't tell us anything, since they're just switches with benefits.  It'd be like taking a picture of a row of valves and saying "which one has a water leak?" Can't tell from the valves.

A 20A breaker is going to tolerate a 60A load for a second or two. That's how table saws get their motor started.

What I wonder, given the symptoms that started this, is whether you have a Lost Neutral.  That would certainly make motors pull more amps than they normally do.  And power companies tend to be *super dumb* about Lost Neutrals. They think they know everything about your power, but they don't.  Their smart meters **can't detect** a Lost Neutral, because it doesn't have access to neutral unless it's a 5-jaw meter.  And you notice they put their data collection rig only on the phase conductors not the neutral.

Nobody pays attention to neutral.

I would say the next step is to check *voltage* to neutral on the two phases (a Kill-a-Watt plugged into any receptacle on each phase would do).  See if the voltage is off-center (two phases add up to 240V, but are not near 120V). See if it moves by >3  volts when you plug a big 120V load into a third circuit. That's a Lost Neutral and it's an easy fix once you convince them it exists.

Comment: I plugged a PowerTronics Probe 100+ in at one point and it registered a 50V hot line impulse and some 20V ones. Does this provide insight with regards to lost neutral or otherwise? Our garbage disposal says 6.3A on it, and it couldn't have been a table saw. I'll plan to do the test you mentioned. Is it correct that to find circuits on two different phases, I should pick receptacles that are on even vs odd slots on the same side of the panel? When you say moves by >3 volts, is that referring to the center moving (e.g. 120 and 120 going to 117 and 123)?  I'll use a hair dryer if that's good.

Comment: @g491 more like 105 and 135V but yeah.  I mean, in a lost neutral, the ability to return neutral current is very limited, so an increase in load on one side swings voltage low on that side. A motor startup current surge would cause extremes of voltage swing (low on the motor's side) making the startup take longer and the current surge last longer.

Comment: I did the test and the most difference I could get it to be with the hair dryer on high was about 1V. I used a kill-a-watt for one outlet and a Klein Tools RT250 on the other.  I tried 4 different circuits - and even and an odd slot on one side of the panel as compared to the reference circuit and an even and an odd slot on the other side of the panel as compared to it.  Is it possible I need to connected to the same circuit that is having issues?  I have alligator clips and bulb socket adapter for my RT250 if needed. Thanks

Comment: @g491 well, 1V is excellent.  My house wouldn't do that well, and I only have one pole (120V) from the utility!  We can cross off "lost neutral" then.   I would look next at series arcing due to loose connections at service wires or feeders, particularly any DIY work. Lug torque really matters. If you have a non-contact thermal tester (laser or FLIR) I would take a close look at panel and subpanel hot and neutral feeder/service connections during/right after a flickering episode. Run it down the neutral bar also.  A too-warm lug suggests arcing there.

Comment: I don't have either of those tools, though could buy one, but before I do, could I just shut off the mains and then tighten everything, or would I potentially miss something by doing that method?  Also, since it's all over the house, would it have to be what's feeding the subpanel or could it still be an individual loose connection and that affect other circuits too? Thanks

Comment: @g491 yeah if you don't have those tools, I wouldn't buy them just for this. They won't fix the power company reported surge anyway.  I am not alarmed by that; I'm much alarmed by the flicker, as that is the hallmark of series arcing, which starts fires.  I'd say the next step is detective work to figure out *exactly which circuits* flicker. Because it can only possibly be in places common to those circuits. E.G. if all the circuits on phase L1 in the subpanel flicker, yet nothing in the main panel does, that can only be in certain specific places.  (the L1 feeder).